# How does sql server choose values in an update statement where there are multiple options?

Tags: sql-server

I have an update statement in SQL server where there are four possible values that can be assigned based on the join.  It appears that SQL has an algorithm for choosing one value over another, and I'm not sure how that algorithm works.

As an example, say there is a table called Source with two columns (Match and Data) structured as below:
(The match column contains only 1's, the Data column increments by 1 for every row)
Match  Data
`--------------------------
 1 1
 1 2
 1 3
 1 4

That table will update another table called Destination with the same two columns structured as below:
Match  Data
`--------------------------
 1 NULL

If you want to update the ID field in Destination in the following way:

> UPDATE
>     Destination
>    SET
>      Data = Source.Data 
>   FROM
>   Destination
>   INNER JOIN
>   Source
>   ON
>   Destination.Match = Source.Match

there will be four possible options that Destination.ID will be set to after this query is run.  I've found that messing with the indexes of Source will have an impact on what Destination is set to, and it appears that SQL Server just updates the Destination table with the first value it finds that matches.

Is that accurate?  Is it possible that SQL Server is updating the Destination with every possible value sequentially and I end up with the same kind of result as if it were updating with the first value it finds?  It seems to be possibly problematic that it will seemingly randomly choose one row to update, as opposed to throwing an error when presented with this situation.

Thank you.

P.S. I apologize for the poor formatting. Hopefully, the intent is clear.

Comment: to identify the affected values you can do a select instead of an update, it will return the values that would be affected by the update, SQL does what you tell it to:
select *
FROM Destination INNER JOIN Source ON Destination.Match = Source.Match

Comment: It's indeterminant.  If you don't *tell* it which to use, it uses whichever if find most convenient.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sets *all* of the results to the Data.  Which one you end up with after the query depends on the order of the results returned (which one it sets last).

Since there's no ORDER BY clause, you're left with whatever order Sql Server comes up with.  That will normally follow the physical order of the records on disk, and that in turn typically follows the clustered index for a table.  But this order isn't set in stone, particularly when joins are involved.  If a join matches on a column with an index other than the clustered index, it may well order the results based on that index instead.  In the end, unless you give it an ORDER BY clause, Sql Server will return the results in whatever order it thinks it can do fastest.

You can play with this by turning your upate query into a select query, so you can see the results.  Notice which record comes first and which record comes last in the source table for each record of the destination table.  Compare that with the results of your update query.  Then play with your indexes again and check the results once more to see what you get.

Of course, it can be tricky here because UPDATE statements are not allowed to use an ORDER BY clause, so regardless of what you find, you should really write the join so it matches the destination table 1:1. You may find the APPLY operator useful in achieving this goal, and you can use it to effectively JOIN to another table and guarantee the join only matches one record.

Comment: It’s a bit funny. I had similar question and I’m getting the same results. It seems that the update statement updates with the first match. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58127836/t-sql-update-table-from-select-flow#

Answer (score 1):

The choice is not deterministic and it can be any of the source rows.

You can try

```
DECLARE @Source TABLE(Match INT, Data INT);

INSERT INTO @Source
VALUES
(1, 1),
(1, 2),
(1, 3),
(1, 4);

DECLARE @Destination TABLE(Match INT, Data INT);

INSERT INTO @Destination
VALUES
(1, NULL);


UPDATE Destination
SET    Data = Source.Data
FROM   @Destination Destination
       INNER JOIN @Source Source
               ON Destination.Match = Source.Match; 

SELECT *
FROM @Destination;
```

And look at the actual execution plan. I see the following.

[image]

The output columns from `@Destination` are `Bmk1000, Match`. `Bmk1000` is an internal row identifier (used here due to lack of clustered index in this example) and would be different for each row emitted from `@Destination` (if there was more than one).

The single row is then joined onto the four matching rows in `@Source` and the resultant four rows are passed into a stream aggregate.

The stream aggregate groups by `Bmk1000` and collapses the multiple matching rows down to one. The operation performed by this aggregate is `ANY(@Source.[Data])`.

The `ANY` aggregate is an [internal aggregate function](https://sqlkiwi.blogspot.com/2011/07/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.html) not available in TSQL itself. No guarantees are made about which of the four source rows will be chosen.

Finally the single row per group feeds into the `UPDATE` operator to update the row with whatever value the `ANY` aggregate returned.

If you want deterministic results then you can use an aggregate function yourself...

```
WITH GroupedSource AS
(
SELECT Match,
       MAX(Data) AS Data
FROM @Source
GROUP BY Match
)
UPDATE Destination
SET    Data = Source.Data
FROM   @Destination Destination
       INNER JOIN GroupedSource Source
               ON Destination.Match = Source.Match;
```

Or use `ROW_NUMBER`...

```
WITH RankedSource AS
(
SELECT Match,
      Data,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Match ORDER BY Data DESC) AS RN
FROM @Source
)
UPDATE Destination
SET    Data = Source.Data
FROM   @Destination Destination
       INNER JOIN RankedSource Source
               ON Destination.Match = Source.Match
WHERE RN = 1;
```

The latter form is generally more useful as in the event you need to set multiple columns this will ensure that all values used are from the same source row. In order to be deterministic the combination of `partition by` and `order by` columns should be unique.