# SQL - Updating field matching fields from 2 other tables

Tags: sql-server

Maybe the coffee hasn't kicked in but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to accomplish a SQL update. Essentially, I have 3 tables and I'm attempting to update a field in table1 with data in table2 based off criteria in table 3.

My 3 tables with sample data:

**tblInvoiceDetail**

```
keyID     InvoiceNumber      ItemID      Qty       Price
--------------------------------------------------------
1            200123          100001       4         400
2            200123          100002       1          10
3            200321          100001       1         100
4            200555          100002       2          20
5            200444          100003       4          20
```

**tblInvoices**

```
keyID      InvoiceNumber      InvoiceDate      CustomerID     InvoiceTotal
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1            200123             3/15/19          456123           410
2            200321             5/31/19          123456           100
3            200555             6/30/19          111222           120
4            200444             6/31/19          111222            20
```

**tblItemUpdate**

```
keyID       OldItem        NewItem
----------------------------------
1           100001         999001
2           100002         999002
3           100003         999003
```

Here's an `UPDATE` statement that I tried but it would not update all the records I expected to.

```
UPDATE 
    tblInvoiceDetail
SET 
    tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID = tblItemUpdate.NewItem
FROM 
    tblInvoiceDetail
INNER JOIN 
    tblItemUpdate ON tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID = tblItemUpdate.OldItem
INNER JOIN 
    tblInvoices ON tblInvoiceDetail.InvoiceNumber = tblInvoices.InvoiceNumber
WHERE
    tblInvoices.InvoiceDate < '2019-06-25'
```

I suspect the problem is in my JOINs so it is not matching all the records I'm wanting.

I want to change the *ItemID* in tblInvoiceDetail and I want it to find the match in *tblItemUpdate.OldItem* and change it to the value in *tblItemUpdate.NewItem*.  However, I only want to update the ItemID if *tblInvoices.InvoiceDate* is prior to 6/25/19.

So, with my sample data in tblInvoiceDetail, only keyIDs 1, 2, and 3 would need to be updated.

I have a lot of records in my live database so I can point to 1 particular thing that didn't work.  I just found several invoices that I thought should have changed but didn't.

Comment: Why the `keyID` 3 should be updated? It's `6/30/19` there which is not `< '2019-06-25'`

Comment: There's no such date as "6/31". Is this possibly doing a string comparison?

Comment: keyID 3 would be updated since it matches to InvoiceNumber 200321 which has a date of 5/31/19.  And yes, 6/31 does not actually exist.  I guess I wasn't thinking when I put in my sample data but it is primarily for illustration purposes being after 6/25.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to change the ItemID in tblInvoiceDetail and I want it to find
>   the match in tblItemUpdate.OldItem and change it to the value in
>   tblItemUpdate.NewItem

So far:

```
UPDATE D SET 
    ItemID = U.NewItem
FROM 
    tblInvoiceDetail AS D
    INNER JOIN tblItemUpdate AS U ON D.ItemID = U.OldItem
```

> However, I only want to update the ItemID if tblInvoices.InvoiceDate
>   is prior to 6/25/19.

You can check for existence with `EXISTS`:

```
UPDATE D SET 
    ItemID = U.NewItem
FROM 
    tblInvoiceDetail AS D
    INNER JOIN tblItemUpdate AS U ON D.ItemID = U.OldItem
WHERE
    EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM tblInvoices AS I WHERE 
            I.InvoiceNumber = D.InvoiceNumber AND -- Link the invoice to update (D) to the invoice table (I)
            I.InvoiceDate < '2019-06-25')
```

Be careful with your `InvoiceDate` data type. It should be `DATE` (or `DATETIME`) and not `VARCHAR`, because it will be bring trouble whenever you compare it against a value otherwise (`'6/25/19'` and `'2019-06-25'` are both dates but they are ***completely different strings***).

Also beware of the existence of multiple rows with the same `OldItem` value on `tblItemUpdate`, as you might be joining a particular row from `tblInvoiceDetail` against N from the `tblItemUpdate` in which case the final `NewItem` value that will be updated is *[indetermined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370462/how-does-sql-server-choose-values-in-an-update-statement-where-there-are-multipl)*.

Comment: Looks good.  I will give this a try.  The dates on my sample data are really for ease of reading. The actual fields are datetimes so I would adjust my statement accordingly.  The OldItem field is unique because they correspond to another table for inventory items in which the ItemID is also unique.  There may be multiple rows in tblInvoiceDetail with the same ItemID but there are not in tblItemUpdate.

Comment: This worked perfectly!  No adjustments other than using the full datetime.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to write this is by using subqueries:

```
UPDATE tblInvoiceDetail
SET ItemID = (SELECT NewItem FROM tblItemUpdate WHERE OldItem = tblInvoiceDetail.ItemID)
WHERE InvoiceNumber IN (
    SELECT id.InvoiceNumber
    FROM tblInvoiceDetail AS id INNER JOIN tblItemUpdate AS iu ON id.ItemID = iu.OldItem
    WHERE id.InvoiceDate < CAST('2019-06-25' AS DATE)
);
```

Ezlo already pointed out the problem when joining to the updated table created multiple rows.

**EDIT:**

Looking closer at your data I also see that you have a bigger problem matching up `ItemID`s with the correct invoices. The primary key in `tblInvoiceDetail` is a compound of both `InvoiceNumber` and `ItemID` yet you don't appear to have that information in the list from `tblItemUpdate`.

Since your sample data includes an invalid date of June 31 it's natural to wonder if a string comparison issue is at play. The primary key issue would potentially rope in more invoices than intended so it wouldn't explain your problem described as fewer rows updating than expected.

Comment: I'll give this a try as well.  I tried adding sample data just to make it "easy" to read and the actual data does not look like this so it isn't a compund of any other data.  I'm mainly looking for what I needed to fix in my update statement.  I guess I wasn't thinking when I put 6/31.  I just wanted to show that it was after 6/25.

Comment: This did not work as copied.  I get an error 'invalid column name 'ItemID' on Line 5.  The ItemID field does not appear in tblInvoices, only in tblInvoiceDetail.  The ItemID needs to match between tblItemUpdate and tblInvoiceDetail and the InvoiceNumber matches between tblInvoices and tblInvoiceDetails.