# T-SQL Update Table From Select Flow

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I was wondering how sql is executed when updating from a select statement when there is no where clause.

Example:

**Table 1**

```
+---------+-----------+
| Column1 |   Column2 |
+---------+-----------+
|    3097 |   Empty   |
|    3097 |   Empty   |
+---------+-----------+
```

**Table 2**

```
+---------+--------------------+
| Column1 |       Column2      |
+---------+--------------------+
|    3097 |   Camberwell       |
|    3097 |   Camberwell North |
+---------+--------------------+
```

```sql
Update a
Set a.column2 = b.column2
From Table1 a 
Inner join Table2 b On a.Column1=b.Column1
```

Does it mean that it’ll update Column2 from a with Camberwell North for all rows?

Comment: yes, this will update Table1  all rows with a.Column1=b.Column1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does sql server choose values in an update statement where there are multiple options?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1370462/how-does-sql-server-choose-values-in-an-update-statement-where-there-are-multipl)

Comment: You are not updating from a select statement. Select and update are two completely different statements, that (may or may not) share clauses such as `from`, `join` and `where`.

Comment: I have just editing my answer....this can acheive using ROWNUMBER()...you can check out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your Question and this may be an interesting Answer. I was able to Test this and determined most standard Joins (**Inner, Left, Full Outer**) gave the Answer of the "First" row and ignored the Second row

[image]

But, a **Right** join did one of each:

[image]

Comment: @@matt can you explain me...One thing...Why 2 result s are different from each other...For just info...

Comment: When you Join on Table B through a Right Join, it returns the names regardless of the `id` match info in Table A. Since the `id` has a match, we get one of each _FOR_ each (4 Sets). It performs a pattern like: **1**1 **2**1 **1**2 **2**2. A Left Join would use Table A, which has no `name` 's but would flip the pattern for the `id` match in Table B but, performs a pattern like **1**1 **1**2 **2**1 **2**2. An Update in this case `set a.id = b.id` from our Right Join we get pattern A for our Values to set. Up until the amount of non-unique values run out i.e: `Camberwell` and `Camberwell North`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried this and was surprised that I didn't get an error. Instead, as you assumed `Table1.Column2` was updated with the results of the first row from `Table2`.

```
   CREATE TABLE #test1 (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(10))
   CREATE TABLE #test2 (Col1 int, Col2 varchar(10))
   INSERT INTO #test1 (col1) Values (3097), (3097)
   INSERT INTO #test2 (Col1, Col2) Values (3097, 'C1'), (3097, 'C2')

    UPDATE #test1 SET Col2 = #test2.Col2 
    FROM #test1 INNER JOIN #test2 ON #test1.Col1=#test2.Col1
```

The results are:

```
    SELECT * FROM #test1
```

```
Col1    Col2
3097    C1
3097    C1
```

Answer (score 1):

After Editing:--

```
WITH X AS 
(
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Column1) As myRowNumber1,Column2 AS Column2tbl1 FROM Table1
)a1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() over (order by Column1) As myRowNumber2,Column2 AS Column2tbl2  FROM Table2
)b1
ON a1.myRowNumber1=b1.myRowNumber2
)
UPDATE X
set Column2tbl1=Column2tbl2
```

This can be Possible using ROWNUMBER().......

Here I Perfroming ROWNUMBER() on Both the Table then Updating the Table1
then

we can acheive...... like row 1 table 1 matches with row 1 table 2. Update to Camberwell. 
Then row 1 table 1 matches row 2 table 2.

**Output:-**
[image]

Comment: But shouldn’t it be like row 1 table 1 matches with row 1 table 2.  Update to Camberwell. Then row 1 table 1 matches row 2 table 2. Update to Camberwell North?

Comment: I have just editing my answer....this can acheive using ROWNUMBER()...you can check out

Comment: I think what's a bit confusing is this:
1 - if you do a select
select * from #table1 a
inner join #table2 b ON a.postcode=b.postcode

you get 4 rows - make sense

2 - when you do an update however, it updates only the 2 rows from table 1 and not 4. I initially thought that because there was 2 matches each row on the second table, it'd update table 1 row 1 and 2 twice. That's not the case however.

When adding CTE it gets a bit more confusing for the same reason but the cte update statement is at the end. In fact it will update table 1 with the first match on table 2 and ignore th rest